# Azure DevOps - Wiql - Query By Id - is there a skip parameter

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to find a possibility to skip X first elements returned by query.
Link to API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0.
Just as with Jira you use maxResults with startAt to create paging.
In AzureDevops Services I see option $top but I do not see option $skip (nor it works).

I can limit my result, but can't page through it.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Why are you wanting to skip the elements?

Comment: Let's say my WIQL returns over 1000 items. I want them for example only by thousands. Process them, then get another 1000 items if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this time, however, the REST API you are using doesn't supported paging.

If a REST API supports paging, there will be skip or continuationtoken parameters in the optional parameters of the document. As shown below:

[image]
[image]

Generally, Paging is supported only by the REST API that gets the lists.

Comment: OK thank you! Do you know if there's another way to filter items and page them?

Comment: Someone looking at this question will think there's no (very effective) workaround, which @jeremy-caney has a very elegant solution for.

Answer (score 0):

While the endpoint does not provide paging itself, I believe you can use WIQL for paging.

- Sort by ID
- Add a constant $top
- if page > 1, add a where ID < last processed ID

Comment: This is useful. Can you improve your explanation, however, by e.g. making sure that the correct parameter names are used (e.g., should it be `$where`?) and that parameter names are flagged as code (e.g., `$top` instead of $top)?